# Change name of uploading file into s3

Tags: php, laravel-5, amazon-s3

I use the below code to store an image to my S3 disk. But using this code i get a random name i.e filename to the image that I'm uploading. So how can i set the filename of `$request->renter_proof` while uploading? Someone please help.

```
$storagePath = Storage::disk('s3')
    ->put('/company/'.Auth::user()->company.'/renter-proof/',
          $request->renter_proof,
          'public');
```

I want the name of the file to be :

```
$imageName = 'Tag '.$request->input('stock_on_rent').'.'.$request->renter_proof->getClientOriginalExtension();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is use **putFileAs()**

I used the below code:

```
$path = "/company/".Auth::user()->company."/renter-proof";        
$imageName = 'Tag '.$request->input('stock_on_rent').'.'.$request->renter_proof->getClientOriginalExtension();    
$storagePath = Storage::disk('s3')->putFileAs($path,$request->renter_proof,$imageName ,'public');
```